# How to get file count over ftp server

Tags: bash

As we all know, "WC -l" command is used to get number of lines of a file,but i couldn't able to use the same command over ftp server.

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run arbitrary shell commands over FTP, you can only run those commands the FTP server accepts.

I'm not aware of any common FTP commands to get the line count of a file. You may want to use SSH instead if possible. Otherwise, you would have to download the file to get the line count.